# findmin/3 の定義

Tags: prolog

findmin/3という述語が出てきますが、定義が載っていませんでした。この定義を教えてください。
findmin/3は、第二引数を非決定性でcallを実行し、その時点の第一引数項をリストに収集した上でその中の最小値を第三引数に単一化する、というものの筈です。

```
チーム(1,巨人).  
チーム(2,阪神).  
チーム(3,中日).  

選手(1,1,阿部,10).   
選手(2,1,杉内,18).  
選手(3,2,金本,6).  
選手(4,2,鳥谷,1).  
選手(5,3,岩瀬,13).  
選手(6,3,谷繁,27).   

各チームから背番号最少の選手を抽出する(_チーム,_選手名,_チーム最小背番号) :-  
チーム(_チームID,_チーム),  
findmin([_背番号,_選手名],選手( _,_チームID,_選手名,_背番号),[_チーム最小背番号,_選手名]).
```

Comment: @尾崎隆大さん、「findmin/3の定義」がどのようなものを意味するのか具体的にシェアしてください。また、コードの部分はMarkdown機能を使って読みやすく整形することができます。ヘルプセンターの「良い質問をするには」が参考になると思います。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: 最終的に質問を書き換えて、findmin/3とはどんなものかを指定してしまったのですが、もともと持たせたかった「なぞなぞ」的な雰囲気は消えてしまいました。だとしても、どんな場合にこんな述語が必要かということを示すことが目的ですからこの姿で構いません。

Comment: クイズ形式を取る事については、以下の議論を読まれた上で判断された方が良いように思いました。マイナスが付いている理由はそういった部分にあるかもしれません。[適切な質問かの討議：クイズ形式の質問 - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489/%e9%81%a9%e5%88%87%e3%81%aa%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%81%ae%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0-%e3%82%af%e3%82%a4%e3%82%ba%e5%bd%a2%e5%bc%8f%e3%81%ae%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f)

Answer (score 1):

処理系は SWI-Prolog 6.6.4 です。`bagof/3` を使ってみました。もっと簡潔な方法があるかとは思いますが、ご参考までにどうぞ。

```
findmin([Num, Name], Y, [Min, Name]) :-
  functor(Y, FY, _),
  arg(2, Y, Team_ID),
  term_variables(Y, [ID, Name, Num]),
  bagof(Num, (ID, Name)^call(FY, ID, Team_ID, Name, Num), NumList),
  min_list(NumList, Min), call(FY, ID, Team_ID, Name, Min).
```

※ 同じチームで背番号が同じで、かつ最小値の選手レコード(現実にはあり得ませんが)を登録した場合、それら全てが抽出されます。`min_list/2` の仕様ですね。

Answer (score -3):

この質問は予め答えが用意されていて、質問者、回答者の関係がクイズのそれに近いものものとして設定したつもりです。
実際にコードの中で使われて具体的な表現から、その述語の定義を想像してみてほしいということです。
私の用意してあった答えは、

```
findmin(A,P,Min) :-
    findall(A,P,L),
    min_list(L,Min).
```

でした。